# Copy contents of one script to another script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm very new to UNIX and I'm currently trying to learn Bash.

I have 3 scripts: `xyz.sh`, `abc.sh` & `wow.sh`. I want to copy content of `xyz.sh` as it is to `wow.sh` using `abc.sh`, i.e., a script to copy one script to another.

xyz.sh:

```
echo "\n code $code \n"
```

abc.sh:

```
while read line
do
   echo $line >> wow.sh
done < xyz.sh
```

On executing abc.sh, the contents of wow.sh are

```
echo "n code $code n"
```

\n gets converted to n, can someone please explain why this is happening and if there is a workaround to keep \n as \n?

Also if a similar question has been asked before, kindly provide a link, I couldn't find any.

Comment: abc.sh: `cat xyz.sh >> wow.sh`

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply Ipor. I oversimplified my question, xyz.sh can have 100s of lines of code & I need to copy a specific portion of it to wow.sh using conditional operators. How would I use cat in that scenario?

Comment: then use `sed` or `awk`

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use those (sed & awk) at work. Is there anyway I can use bash to accomplish this?

Comment: use `read -r` to prevent it from interpreting the backslashes (look up `read` in [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html)) and put [quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) around `$line` to prevent word-splitting. (or just use `cp`, `sed`, `awk` or `perl`)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to append (the contents of) `xyz.sh` to `wow.sh`, the simplest way is this:

```
cat xyz.sh >> wow.sh
```

Using `read` to get the same result is not as straight forward as it may seem. `\` is a special character in the shell. You would have to use the `-r` option, which means:

```
    -r      do not allow backslashes to escape any characters
```

`cat` does this by default. Moreover `read` is not the correct tool to do this kind of operations anyhow. Intuition should tell you the same when you compare the syntax for both commands.

There's one more command you might be interested in. It is the `source` builtin, also called by `.`. If you source a file from your script, it works to the effect as if the sourced file's contents were present in the script. So putting this line in `wow.sh`:

```
. xyz.sh
```

or

```
source xyz.sh
```

doesn't copy the contents of `xyz.sh` to `wow.sh`, but the very contents of `xyz.sh` are executed while `wow.sh` is executed, as if it were present in the script. Of course only if the file `xyz.sh` is present during the `wow.sh` script execution.

Comment: Thank you fro your response tomas, I'm aware of ".", it works somewhat like importing libraries in other languages. I don't need to execute a file before another file, I need to copy specific portions of a script to another script verbatim using conditional operators. I was using if constructs inside my "while read". I'll try read -r as per your suggestion.